# Padding a csv value with 0's

Tags: csv

I have this csv file that I would like to sort on the 20th and 21st field. For example the data in those fields are P1,PK5. My challenge is that when I sort on those fields they are not in order as I would have liked. It seems like I have to pad those fields to the longest value in that fields data.

```
OrderNum,MerrillRecipientID,CustomerClass,MerrillItemNum,PODTemplateID,GridCode,AetnaDocID,MemberID,FirstName,MI,LastName,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,State,Zip,Country,OEL,PalletNum,PckgNum,IMBCode,ProcDate
"M394993","M39499300010000001","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011250","MEBB04CB","Name","","Name","address","","","City","SC","29170-2043","","*******AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 29033","P1","PK5","2031100094470495539729170204309","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000002","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011572","MEBB07GB","Name","G","Name","address","","","City","SC","29020-2912","","*********AUTO**SCH 3-DIGIT 290","P1","PK1","3031100094470495580529020291210","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000003","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011693","MEBB08MP","Name","B","Name","address","","","City","SC","29061-9447","","*********AUTO**SCH 3-DIGIT 290","P1","PK2","3031100094470495583729061944757","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000004","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011751","MEBB097M","Name","A","Name","address","","","City","SC","29645-0433","","*************AUTO**3-DIGIT 296","P1","PK31","3031100094470495629629645043333","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000005","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012075","MEBB0K4L","Name","E","Name","address","","","City","SC","29682-9634","","*************AUTO**3-DIGIT 296","P1","PK33","3031100094470495637929682963428","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000006","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012437","MEBB0TWQ","Name","R","Name","address","","","City","SC","29505-3030","","*******AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 29501","P1","PK24","2031100094470495556429505303050","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000007","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012750","MEBB0YJY","Name","L","Name","address","","","City","SC","29642-3006","","***********AUTO**5-DIGIT 29642","P1","PK38","2031100094470495567529642300601","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
```

So from the above data I need to have the file look like so:

```
OrderNum,MerrillRecipientID,CustomerClass,MerrillItemNum,PODTemplateID,GridCode,AetnaDocID,MemberID,FirstName,MI,LastName,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,State,Zip,Country,OEL,PalletNum,PckgNum,IMBCode,ProcDate
"M394993","M39499300010000001","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011250","MEBB04CB","Name","","Name","address","","","City","SC","29170-2043","","*******AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 29033","P1","PK05","2031100094470495539729170204309","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000002","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011572","MEBB07GB","Name","G","Name","address","","","City","SC","29020-2912","","*********AUTO**SCH 3-DIGIT 290","P1","PK01","3031100094470495580529020291210","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000003","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011693","MEBB08MP","Name","B","Name","address","","","City","SC","29061-9447","","*********AUTO**SCH 3-DIGIT 290","P1","PK02","3031100094470495583729061944757","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000004","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1011751","MEBB097M","Name","A","Name","address","","","City","SC","29645-0433","","*************AUTO**3-DIGIT 296","P1","PK31","3031100094470495629629645043333","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000005","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012075","MEBB0K4L","Name","E","Name","address","","","City","SC","29682-9634","","*************AUTO**3-DIGIT 296","P1","PK33","3031100094470495637929682963428","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000006","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012437","MEBB0TWQ","Name","R","Name","address","","","City","SC","29505-3030","","*******AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 29501","P1","PK24","2031100094470495556429505303050","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
"M394993","M39499300010000007","0GH","3GH000503","PDP","BO","1012750","MEBB0YJY","Name","L","Name","address","","","City","SC","29642-3006","","***********AUTO**5-DIGIT 29642","P1","PK38","2031100094470495567529642300601","3GH000503","August 26, 2013"
```

the P1 field could be P100 and so I would need to pad P1 to P001. But really it justs need to be whatever the max length is. I can sort the file on the two fields but not sure how to pad them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what environment are you in?  do you want to modify the csv files themselves?  with python, perl, or something like that?  need more information!

Comment: To answer your question, we need some idea of what programming language or tool you're using to access the .csv.  Knowing the database type (Oracle, MSSQL, mySql, etc) would also help. Q: You're trying to read an existing CSV (and not write or modify the .csv), correct?

Comment: Sorry, I am on a linux system. SUSE. I do want to modify the csv file with a shell script. I am trying to modify the csv to pad those two fields to whatever the longest value is in those fields.

Comment: Pad after the letters

Answer (score 1):

okay, since nothing else has been forthcoming, here's a quick python (2.x or 3.x) script which will do what you need:

```
import sys
import csv

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

rows = [row for row in reader]
max_len = max([len(row[20]) for row in rows[1:]])

writer.writerow(rows[0])
for row in rows[1:]:
    while len(row[20]) < max_len:
        row[20] = 'PK0' + row[20][2:]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

if you save this as, say, `pad.py`, then you can use it like so:

```
$ cat /path/to/my_csv_file.csv | python /path/to/pad.py > /path/to/my_new_csv_file.csv
```

and will create `my_new_csv_file.csv` in the format you need.  Since the script acts on `stdin` and outputs to `stdout`, you can use it in many different ways to suit your purposes.

Hope this helps.